# Error replacing ZFS disk

Tags: zfs, truenas

I’m trying to replace a disk in a TrueNAS ZFS pool and I’m getting the error `cannot replace 5885333735856859460 with ada6: already in replacing/spare config; wait for completion or use 'zpool detach'`

`zpool status` shows

```
    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    Data                                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/d135c3aa-526b-11e5-9e77-fcaa14286713  ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
        gptid/03f4d51c-3c63-11e5-8cea-fcaa14286713  ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
        gptid/085d91b7-9521-11e5-b5cf-fcaa14286713  ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
      raidz1-1                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
        gptid/c6e9543f-f78d-11e2-abaa-003048d79b60  ONLINE       0     0     0
        5885333735856859460                         FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/gptid/c77a9a39-f78d-11e2-abaa-003048d79b60
        gptid/da5ff311-eef1-11ea-a29e-fcaa14286713  ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native

errors: No known data errors
```

I’d previously tried the replacement through the web interface but aborted it by powering off the machine after it was locked up for a day or so, physically removed the new disk and replaced it with the original disk, and it resilvered to an error-free state. I’ve now once again physically replaced the old disk with the new disk, and I get the above error whether I try to replace the disk through the web interface or using the command line. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this using the command

```
zpool replace -f -o ashift=9  Data 5885333735856859460 gptid/65a0a675-c080-11eb-b350-fcaa14286713
```

rather than

```
zpool replace Data 5885333735856859460 gptid/65a0a675-c080-11eb-b350-fcaa14286713
```

(where `65a0a675-c080-11eb-b350-fcaa14286713` is the raw ID of the data partition on the drive).

The most important clue is the message in the output of `zpool status` that the devices are configured with non-native block size (I don’t recall configuring the block size anywhere). The `ashift` parameter changes the blocksize of the device when adding it to the pool. The pool is now happily resilvering.